# Starting Rserve in debug mode and printing variables from Tableau to R

Tags: r, tableau-api, rserve

I can't start Rserve in debug mode.
I wrote these commands in R:

```
library(Rserve)
Rserve(debug=T, args="RS-enable-control", quote=T, port = 6311)
library(RSclient)
c=RSconnect(host = "localhost", port = 6311)
RSeval(c, "xx<-12")
RSeval(c, "2+6")
RSeval(c, "xx")
RSclose(c)
install.packages("fpc")
```

I placed the Rserve_d.exe in the same directory where the R.dll file is located. But when I launch it and I launch Tableau with the Rserve connection I can't see anything in the debug console, just these few lines.

```
Rserve 1.7-3 () (C)Copyright 2002-2013 Simon Urbanek
$Id$
Loading config file Rserv.cfg
Failed to find config file Rserv.cfg
Rserve: Ok, ready to answer queries.
-create_server(port = 6311, socket = <NULL>, mode = 0, flags = 0x4000)
INFO: adding server 000000000030AEE0 (total 1 servers)
```

I tried another solution by the command Rserve(TRUE) in R, but I can't see the transactions between R and Tableau neither in the Rstudio console.

I wanted then to print the output of the variable in R from the R-script function, by print(.arg1). But nothing appears in the R console
but when I run print in the R console it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/dream-team-combining-tableau-and-r/)*, RServe should be run with the following command to enable debugging:

```
R CMD Rserve_d
```

An alternative is to use the ‘write.csv’ command within the calculated field that calls an R script, as suggested by [this FAQ document from Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/media/tableau_and_r_faq.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Starting Rserve_d.exe from command line works. Most likely you have multiple instances of Rserve running and Tableau is sending requests to one that is not Rserve_d running in the command line.

Did you try killing all Rserve processes and then starting Rserve_d from command line?

If you don't want to run from the command line you can try starting Rserve in process from RStudio by typing `run.Rserve()` then using `print()` statements in your Tableau calculated fields for things you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

In the R bin directory, you have two executables Rserve for normal execution and Rserve.dbg for debug execution. Use

```
R CMD Rserve.dbg
```

My OS is CENTOS7 and I am using the R installation from anaconda. If your RServe debug executable has a different name you should be using that.